# Elastic search sorting not working as expected

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, integer

I am using elastic search version 1.2.1 and trying to sort results on an integer field but it's not working the way I believe it has to and I can't sort in asc or desc order. I am using Sense extension of Chrome and Elastic search listens port 9200 at localhost.

Here's how I defined index:

```
PUT keyword_test
```

Then I added mapping for keyword_test index:

```
PUT /keyword_test/_mapping/keyword
{
    "keyword": {
        "properties" : {
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "search_date": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "keyword": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "analyzed"
            },
            "count": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added different keywords with different counts and try to search among them with the query below:

```
GET _search 
{
    "sort": {
        "count": {
            "order": "asc",
            "ignore_unmapped": true
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
           "keyword": "iphone"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the result below:

```
"hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "keyword_test",
            "_type": "keyword",
            "_id": "8",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "id": 8,
               "count": 9000,
               "keyword": "iphone 5s",
               "search_date": "2015-05-05"
            },
            "sort": [
               9000
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "keyword_test",
            "_type": "keyword",
            "_id": "10",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "id": 10,
               "count": 9500,
               "keyword": "iphone 6 plus",
               "search_date": "2015-05-05"
            },
            "sort": [
               9500
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "keyword_test",
            "_type": "keyword",
            "_id": "9",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "id": 9,
               "count": 9100,
               "keyword": "iphone 6",
               "search_date": "2015-05-05"
            },
            "sort": [
               9100
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
```

Result should be 9000, 9100, 9500 order but it is in 9000, 9500, 9100 order. I also get SearchParseException if I remove ignore_unmapped. What should I do? Am I missing some mapping for count field? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Suggestion:  Can you just repeat the process and check cause i myself tried this on my local system. It worked as it is  expected to work .For me result were ok.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried the same scenario and got the same result again. I am using 1.2.1 version by the way, are you using the same version and getting correct results?

Comment: my ES version is 1.4.5

Comment: @BurakA.the `searchparseexception` most probably is due to the fact the search is across all indexes in the cluster if you change to index specific search  `GET  keyword_test/_search`  and remove `ignore_unmapped` you should stop getting the exception. I'm still not sure why you are getting the strange results , works for me in 1.2.1

Comment: @AkashYadav I think there may be a difference between 1.2.1 and 1.4.5. I will try 1.4.5 too but I need to make it work for 1.2.1 since it is used in our production server.

Comment: Just to rule out a parsing difference, make sure to use a json array (of only one sort criterion) inside sort.   `"sort": [ { ... } ]`